# Unordered List with numbers instead of bullet points

Tags: html, css, css-counter

I have a Terms and Conditions file that I need to get on the webiste. However there are a lot of clauses and points such as 2, 2.1, 2.1.1 etc.

I thought I could do an unordered list and use css to get rid of the bullet points. I realize it may seem a bit long-winded but I am no HTML expert and I am also not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `counters`.

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: item;
}
li {
  display: block;
}
li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".")". ";
  counter-increment: item;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <ol>
    <li>testing</li>
    <li>testing</li>
  </ol>
</ol>
```

This will produce:

> 1. test
> 2. test
>
>    2.1. testing
>
>    2.2. testing

Read more here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters

Comment: `before` selector not supported in IE7 and down (and partially IE8)

Comment: is there a way to change the colour of the numbers produced by the ol counter

Comment: Add a `color` style to the `li:before` rule.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ol`

Like this:

```
<ol>
  <li>Hello 
   <ol>
    <li>Hello 1</li>
    <li>Hello 2</li>
    <li>Hello 3</li>
   </ol>
  </li>
  <li>hi</li>
  <li>hey</li>
</ol>
```

Output:

[image]

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried an ordered list?

```
<ol>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ol.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to change/remove the bullets but if you want to use numbers you will have to use an Ordered List.

To remove the bullets just use this line in CSS:

```
list-style-type:none
```